# XmlStarlet update value of first node

Tags: xml

In my xml-file I want to change the value of only the first node. When I execute

{xml ed -u //*[local-name()='KnopenTakkenPositie']/*[local-name()='Koppositie']/*[local-name()='Kilometerlint'] -v "xxxxx" MTPS108_TC001_5output.xml}

all node values (5) are replaced.

Does anybody know how to do the trick? Thanks and greets, Frank

Answer (score 0):

The answer:
xml sel -t -m "//*[local-name()='KnopenTakkenPositie'][position() = '2']/*[local-name()='Koppositie']/*[local-name()='Kilometerlint']" -v "." -o " " MTPS108_TC001_5output.xml